# Inference engines in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, protege, rule-engine, swrl, inference-engine

I would like to know if there is a way to use inference engines (like Drools) in Neo4j like we can in Protege (using plugins like SWRL and JessTab). 
I couldn't find much information regarding this on the web.
Any leads will be appreciated.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/44678792/7879193

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of projects around this, the most recent one being GraphScale

http://derivo.de/en/products/graphscale/

You can find a great blog post about its usage here :

https://neo4j.com/blog/neo4j-rdf-graph-database-reasoning-engine/